# Recursively executing Linux pipe commands in c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, recursion

My implementation uses recursion to execute commands with multiple pipes so that I would in theory only need 2 pipes. However, after the second iteration read() prevents my program from halting. I can only execute the " ls -la | cat -A" part of "ls -la | cat -A | cat -A | cat -A" but my program will get stuck at the read() and never exit. If I comment out the reads that are causing this problem, the program gets to the end and exits, but of course then I have no output. Does anyone know why this is happening? I've also tried an iterative implementation, but I get the same error.

```
char* buf[1000];
int recursion_fd[2];
int output_size;
auto pipe_recursion_fd = pipe(recursion_fd);


void execute_pipe(vector<vector<string>> commands)
{

    //PUT THE COMMAND INTO ARRAY TO CALL WITH EXEC
    char* args[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for(int i=0; i < commands.at(0).size();++i)
    {
        int size = commands.at(0).at(i).size() + 1;
        args[i] = new char[size];
        strcpy(args[i],commands.at(0).at(i).c_str()); 
    }

    //CREAT PIPE AND FORK
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int pid = fork();

    //CHILD
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(recursion_fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);

        //dup(recursion_fd[0]);
        //dup(fd[1]);

        int exec_status = execvp(args[0],args);
        cout << "exec failed - not a valid command" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    //PARENT
    if(pid != 0)
    {
        waitpid(pid,NULL,WNOHANG);
        //close(fd[1]);

        //THIS IS THE RECURSION CONDITION, THE LAST ITERATTION SHOULD PRINT 0
        cout << "   num pipes " << num_pipes(commands) << endl;

        if(num_pipes(commands) > 0)
        {
            //THIS CAUSES HOLD
            output_size = read(fd[0],buf,sizeof(buf));

            printf("inside buf:: %s \n",buf); //PRINT TO TEST ITERATIONS
            write(recursion_fd[1],buf,output_size);
            commands.erase(commands.begin()); //erase completed command
            commands.erase(commands.begin()); //erase pipe
            execute_pipe(commands);
        }

        else
        {
            //THIS CAUSES HOLD
            output_size = read(fd[0],buf,sizeof(buf));

            return;
        }

    }

}

void test_execute_pipe()
{
    string command;
    cout << ":: ";
    getline(cin,command);
    vector<vector<string>> test = seperate_command(command);

    cout << "test size = " << test.size() << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < test.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int c=0; c < test.at(i).size(); ++c)
        {
            cout << test.at(i).at(c) << "~";
        }
        cout <<endl;    
    }

    memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
    execute_pipe(test);

    //cout << "right before buf print" << endl;
    printf("buf:: \n");
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,output_size);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    test_execute_pipe();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using something like `cat -A`? You can do the same thing inside C without neeeding a pipe.

Comment: That is just to test my piping function. I don't need the specific output from cat -A. This is just an exercise to see If I can simulate the piping of linux.

Comment: Ah, indeed. C is not necessarily a good replacement for a robust shell script, mind you, or leveraging the shell from C.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to assume that you can write an arbitrary amount of data into one end of a pipe, and then retrieve all of it from the other end. But you can't. There is a bit of buffer available but not much; if you write more than that before reading, the `write` will block.

Also, this:

```
dup2(recursion_fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
```

seems to assume that `recursion_fd` has been set to something, but I don't see where.

Comment: I accidentally left out the piping of recursion_fd in my post, I have edited it back in. Is there some way I can clear the pipe to avoid hitting the buffer limit, or would I have to make a new pipe every iteration?

Comment: @S.Steverson You clear the pipe by reading from it :). You really don't want to execute​ the processes serially; you need to get them all running so that the data flows freely through the pipeline. That optimizes resource utilisation and avoids deadlocks. You could instead sequentially execute the processes, putting the intermediate data into temporary files but that kind of defeats the purpose of pipelining. Do you really want to wait for the whole thing to finish before you see the first line?

Comment: In short, yes, you need a separate pipe for each communications link. Fortunately, you don't need to pay the piper.